# Omitting "the" while using "most" before adverbs

Tags: meaning, prepositions

As far as I know, when using "most" as an adverb to describe a verb we can omit "the" .

> 1-They all cried, but Claire cried ***the most***.
>
> 1'-They all cried, but Claire cried ***most***.

But when using "most" before an adverb, should I use "the" before "most" ?

> 2-The question that is asked ***the most often***.
>
> 2'-The question that is asked ***most often***. (It is the most often asked
>   question of a number of questions or It is just asked very often?)

Comment: As "most" in "most often" is also an adverb, therefore using "the" would be erroneous.

Comment: It could be needless but I don't think it would be erroneous.

Comment: Articles are basically adjectives and adjectives by definition point to a noun or a pronoun and not to an adverb or any other part of speech.

Comment: You can use the before "most" when it was used as an adverb. For example: "It was Aunt Margaret who complained the most." (https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/most_1)

Comment: While constructing a superlative form you can use "the" before adverbs. You are giving misinformation about the usage of "the" .

Comment: The use of *the* is optional. It's certainly not ungrammatical to use it. It's simply personal preference if you want to include it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - The question that is asked the most often is: "How can I find a job?"
> - The question that is asked most often is: "How can I find a job?"

Both are correct, and the meaning is essentially the same.

Examples found online:

> - ["Which pairs of justices agree the most often?"](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/volokh-conspiracy/wp/2014/06/23/which-pairs-of-justices-agree-the-most/?utm_term=.2dd953ccb56e) *The Washington Post* 2014
> - ["Financial advisers who brag the most often give you the least"](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/find-financial-advisers-who-can-give-your-portfolio-a-personal-touch-2018-08-20) marketwatch.com

See https://ludwig.guru/s/the+most+often for some additional examples using "the"